# Added hair particles don't show in object mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

As shown in the pictures below when I add hair particles via the particle editor they aren't visible in the object mode, the same goes when I tried rendering it, the hair wasn't visible. I'm thinking the problem might have something to do with the fact that I'm using an armature, so maybe Blender gets the position of the hair wrong? I would be thankful if anyone has an idea what I can do about it.

**[image: strong text]**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean they aren't visible? I can see hair particles there just fine.

Comment: The hair you see on the body is fine, but you see the hair I added afterwards, like the one in the face doesn't show.

Comment: Hmmm... Check that the normals aren't flipped on the face perhaps? Check the inside of the dogs head to see if it's going the wrong way? Draw a line from where you can see hair to where you cannot to check where it goes wrong.

Comment: I think I found my mistake, I forgot I declared where the hair is suppose to be with a vertex group, so the hair is obviously only visible in that area. But thank you for your help!